# How to display a rendered field in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a very specific problem, and I'm hoping someone out there can come to my rescue!  I am using Address Field in Drupal 7 to have my users enter addresses for people that want my product mailed to.  Using Views Export Data, I convert the data they enter on the form into a .csv file which allows me to automate the process of sending out there mail.

My problem is that Address Field saves each piece of data from the address seperately in the database.  The address displays properly, with linebreaks, when shown on the node.  In Views, if I create a list of the data, it still displays properly, but for some reason Views Data Export does not render the address properly.  Instead, it takes the data and strings it out on one line without breaks.

What I would like to do would be to save the rendered address field in the database so I could call up the properly formatted address.  There is a token, [field_address] which displays the address properly for all purposes except Views Data Export.  Is there a way to insert a token into a custom field so it will save the full address in a databse?

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you!
-JB

Comment: Did you get any solution for above query?

Answer (score 1):

The addressfield tokens module might help you. http://drupal.org/project/addressfield_tokens